# Как сделать, чтобы объект рисовался в окне?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

В общем, я хочу создать объект который имел форму 2D квадрата. И в будущем изменять только параметры объекта. Но функция `glutDisplayFunc` не может обработать функцию объекта из класса.

Как мне скрепить OpenGL с объектом?

1. `.h`-файл:

   ```
   class Printer
   {
   public:
       void vertexs();
       void Initialize();
       void Dwar();
   };

   void vertexs()
   {
       float i[8] = {0.0, 0.0,
                     0.1, 0.0,
                     0.0, 0.1,
                     0.1, 0.1};
       glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
       glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, i);
       glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 2);
       glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
       glFlush();
       glutSwapBuffers(); 
   }

   void Printer::Initialize()
   {
       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
       glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); 
       glClearDepth(1);
       gluOrtho2D(200.0, -200.0, 200.0, -100.0);

       glPointSize(1.0);
       glLineWidth(0.1);
   }

   void Printer::Dwar()
   {
       glutDisplayFunc(vertexs);
   }
   ```
2. `.cpp`-файл:

   ```
   int main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
       Printer printer;
       printer.vertexs();
       printer.Dwar();
       printer.Initialize();

       glutInit(&argc, argv);
       glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GL_STENCIL | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE); 
       glutInitWindowSize(1920, 1080);
       glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
       glutCreateWindow("OpenGL");

       glutPostRedisplay();

       glutMainLoop();
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: заведите себе struct под хранение координат квадрата и... храните в нем координаты.

Comment: Нужно сделать ф-цию `vertexs` статичной.

Comment: Интересно, а без преодоления специально создаваемых трудностей никак нельзя?

Comment: просто после каждого вызова инструкции 

    glBegin GL_QUADS

меняете свойства и все

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте функцию-враппер.

```
Printer printer;

void wrap_vertexs() {
    printer.vertexs();
}

void Printer::Dwar()
{
    glutDisplayFunc(&wrap_vertexs);
}
```

К сожалению, в отличие от большинства нормальных Api с коллбэками, glut не поддерживает такой штуки, как userdata, поэтому по-нормальному сделать то, что Вы хотите, не получится.

Comment: "glut не поддерживает такой штуки, как userdata..."

Может посоветуйте какую-нибудь нормальную графическую кросс-платформенную библиотеку (API)...
Думаю перейти на SDL.

Comment: Не получается ругается на glutDisplayFunc(&wrap_vertexs);

.h: In member function ‘void Printer::Dwar()’:
.h:45:18: error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say ‘&Printer::wrap_vertexs’ [-fpermissive]
 glutDisplayFunc(&wrap_vertexs);//рисование
                  ^
.h:45:30: error: cannot convert ‘void (Printer::*)()’ to ‘void (*)()’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void glutDisplayFunc(void (*)())’
 glutDisplayFunc(&wrap_vertexs);//рисование

Comment: wrap_vertexs должно быть не методом, а обычной функцией, иначе никакого смысла во враппере нет.

SDL всяко лучше, чем glut.

Answer (score 0):

А тут у вас не ошибка случайно? Добавьте Printer:: ! Да кстати, правильно Draw, а не Dwar

```
void vertexs()
{
    float i[8]={0.0,0.0,
```

OpenGL'ем баловался последний раз в школе, но вы помоему пытаетесь совместить одновременно стандартную OpenGL библиотеку с glut? Какие ошибки выдает компилятор? И еще - сразу идет инициализация, а затем отрисовка, а не так как у вас, в обратном порядке. Хотя в вашем случае это не важно, вы и так пытаетесь совместить почти не совместимые вещи в своем коде.